# Highcharts : how to set first category on Y-axis in a line chart?

Tags: highcharts, line, axis, offset

I have a very simple case of Line chart with categories placed "on" ticks on the X-axis.

How can I set the first category tick to be on the Y-axis (set y=0 and x="1st category" to be the origin of the chart) ?
There always seem to be an arbitrary offset between the Y-axis and where the Lines actually start.I'd like to cancel it.

I almost got there by using a negative "offset" on YAxis, but it is unaesthetic (since it leave a bit of the X-axis on the left of the Y-axis), and the value of this offset should depend on the width of the charts (not flexible).

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginLeft: 30
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            tickInterval: 1,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 2
        },
        yAxis: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            tickWidth: 1,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 2,
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            tickInterval: 50,
            gridLineWidth: 0
            /*,offset:-26*/
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [100, 125, 150, 125, 90]
        },{
            data: [100, 80, 90, 80, 70]
        },{
            data: [100, 90, 80, 60, 180]
        }]
    });
```

Please have a look at my example : http://jsfiddle.net/SineDie/xajHE/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889786/highcharts-y-axis-padding-in-a-bar-chart.  Look at the accepted answer.  It's an issue with categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it to work by abandoning categories, and specifying the indivual x and y points in the dataseries. You can do this using the Date.UTC function to calculate dates from the year values.

Also, Use a datetime x-axis to render the dates, with a minPadding of 0 to make sure the first point appears on the y axis.

```
  xAxis: {
        type:'datetime',
        tickLength: 2,
        minPadding:0,
        startOnTick:true
    },
 series: [{
        data: [[Date.UTC(1990,0,1,0,0,0),100], [Date.UTC(1991,0,1,0,0,0),125], [Date.UTC(1992,0,1,0,0,0),150], [Date.UTC(1993,0,1,0,0,0),125], [Date.UTC(1994,0,1,0,0,0),90]]
    },{
        data: [[Date.UTC(1990,0,1,0,0,0),100], [Date.UTC(1991,0,1,0,0,0),80], [Date.UTC(1992,0,1,0,0,0),90], [Date.UTC(1993,0,1,0,0,0),80], [Date.UTC(1994,0,1,0,0,0),70]]
    },{
        data: [[Date.UTC(1990,0,1,0,0,0),100], [Date.UTC(1991,0,1,0,0,0),90], [Date.UTC(1992,0,1,0,0,0),80], [Date.UTC(1993,0,1,0,0,0),60], [Date.UTC(1994,0,1,0,0,0),180]]
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D6ymT/

Comment: Here we are 4 year later, this fix is still required for categories?